# I want to get resize window notification on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, delegates

I am new to osx developing I have read on documentations about windowDidResized:
method , but I am failing to get its delegate .
It is never get called for me , I have included appKit/appKit.h as it said in docs
but the delegate method never triggers
(I am trying to get it inside my `NSViewController`)

can some one please make a simple example how do i get that delegate please?

what I have tried to do is:

```
 -(void)loadView
 {
 //blabla
self.view.window.delegate = [self.view.window delegate];
//blabla ..
 }


- (void)windowDidResize:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"window Resized");
}
```

I am expecting non xib usage samples please :)
thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view probably shouldn't be a window's delegate. 
Normally the delegate for a window would be a controller object in the Model View Controller paradigm.

You can however use NSNotificationCenter to add an object as an observer for a specific NSNotification from a specific object. 
( be sure to remove the observer in its dealloc method if not earlier )

NSWindow class sends many different notifications.

Comment: I am sorry , but I don't get.should I implement something more?
I just called `NSViewController` from `appDelegate` (like in *iOS*)
could you please link me what is that mysterious paradigm ?
and thanks for the answer I will check is asap.